# with main css messed up bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trapped in the hole of bootstrap css messed up with my application main css.

I am using angular-bootstrap'popover, but the popover's arrow was messed up. like this:

[image]

and the css:

[image]

the css '.card .card-panel .card-body .arrow' is the css in my main css file. and the '.test-popover .popover.right > .arrow' is what i am wanted! I don't why the main css has the higher priority！ How can I solve this?

---

Finally I reappeared this see [here Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNTRx7ER8cuq1w2ObeuU?p=preview)

the main.css is like this

```
.card .card-panel .card-body .arrow {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-size: 14px 9px;
  background-position: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Because of css specificity.

Comment: You see we cant debug img plz post your code or online demo

Comment: @priya_singh hmm, anything can be done to solve this?

Comment: @Rahul Sure, I will make a plunker.

Comment: Yes. You can. By increasing specificity of your code.  For ref https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: do what @Rahul say , maybe you make a multiple selection of same class ; main css higher priority because you put it at last  this is how it work : 
<link1>

<link2>

<link3>

link3 will overwrite link2,1 common selectors

Comment: Most likely `.test-popover .popover .card .card-panel .card-body .arrow { ...` will make it more specific (considering that the card is under a .popover element)

Comment: @OvidiuDolha the bad new is that my popover is placing like this:<div class="card"><div class="card-panel"><div class="card-body"><popover>.

Comment: @Kain I am using Gulp and LESS, you mean that should I import the main.less before the bootstrap.less?

Comment: to load your css in right way you need to load libraries then external resources then styles for this page only then style inside head tag

Comment: example for about page : bootstrap.ext >  material.ext  > header.ext > index.ext > about.ext >  CSS { property } .

Comment: Yes, you can fix it with increased specificity in your CSS but I think the actual problem is that you're misusing `.card`. That entire view is wrapped in a `.card`. Why? You may fix this problem with CSS but you'll likely continue to chase your tail.

Comment: @Will It's just a piece of my of application, not the whole page. Yes,  I think the main.css will continue get me in trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the Bootstrap `card` related HTML and it works as expected.

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
        <h2>Here is a list a weapons</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in weaponItems">
      <div class="col-xs-12"> <!-- not needed -->
        <div class="col-xs-6" ng-click="selectItem(item)" uib-popover-template="'popover.html'" popover-is-open="isOpen && item === selectedItem" popover-trigger="click" popover-placement="right">
          <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body" style="min-height:120px;">
              <div><b>Category:</b>&nbsp;{{item.title}}</div>
              <p><b>Desc:</b>&nbsp;{{item.desc}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="panel" style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="{{item.img}}" height="120px" width="auto">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The spacing will be slightly different but you can correct that by removing the superfluous `.col-xs-12` wrapper within `<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in weaponItems">`. The `.row` is handling that stuff. Having nested cols like that is what causes the extra padding.

Comment: Thanks, Will! I am going to either delete the 'card' element or rename the '.arrow' class.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to load your main css after bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

This will overwrite bootstrap css by your main css

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem! I added a more specificity css sheet to my popover, solved this perfectly! Thanks for all your help!